# Append to HTML Table using Javascript with Data-elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have four arrays

```
arrayOne['orange','blue','green','red','yellow','purple','gray','tan','pink','violet']
arrayTwo['1001','1003','3453','78934','2389','3','8934']
arrayThree['TV','phone','laptop']
arrayFour['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10']
```

I am making a table in html

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
      <th>Column 4</th>
   </tr>
</thead>
```

I have a script that opens a modal and appends to the table I have tried to get it working for two columns but it is only populating the first column with ArrayOne contents

```
for (row = 0; row <$(this).data("arrayOne").length; row++ ){
  $("#myModal").find(".table").append("<tr>
  <td>"+$(this).data("arrayOne")[row]+"</td>"); 

  for (j = 0; j <$(this).data("arrayTwo").length; j++ ){
    $("#myModal").find(".table").append("<tr>
    <td>"+$(this).data("arrayTwo")[j]+"</td></tr></tbody></table>");
  } 
}
```

With the code above it only prints out as

```
column1    column2    column 3    column 4
orange
blue
green
red
....
violet
```

The end result should look something like this

```
column1    column2    column 3    column 4
orange     1001       TV          1
blue       1003       phone       2
green      3453       laptop      3
red        78934                  4
yellow     2389                   5
```

Etc, Etc

Comment: you should try to close your `<tr>` before opening a new one.. EDIT: one of your problems is also that by appending raw html code, you should fill rows with all of your 4 arrays at once, because a `<tr>` is the horizontal part of that table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `arrayOne` has all the required rows, and on other arrays the rows may be blank, you can do something like,

```
 arrayOne.forEach(function(value, key){
     let firstColumn = arrayOne[key],
         secondColumn = arrayTwo[key]?arrayTwo[key]:"",
         thirdColumn = arrayThree[key]?arrayThree[key]:"",
         fourthColumn = arrayFour[key]?arrayFour[key]:"";

     $("#myModal").find(".table").append('<tr><td>'+firstColumn+'</td><td>'+secondColumn+'</td><td>'+thirdColumn+'</td><td>'+fourthColumn+'</td></tr>');
 });
```

Comment: will end up with numerous `"undefined"` since arrays are different lengths

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
for (row = 0; row <$(this).data("arrayOne").length; row++ )
{
    var valOne = ($(this).data("arrayOne")[row]!=null)?$(this).data("arrayOne")[row]:"";
    var valTwo = ($(this).data("arrayTwo")[row]!=null)?$(this).data("arrayTwo")[row]:"";
    var valThree = ($(this).data("arrayThree")[row]!=null)?$(this).data("arrayThree")[row]:"";
    var valFour = ($(this).data("arrayFour")[row]!=null)?$(this).data("arrayFour")[row]:"";

    $("#myModal").find(".table").append("<tr><td>"+valOne+"</td><td>"+valTwo+"</td><td>"+valThree+"</td><td>"+valFour+"</td></tr>");
}
```

Comment: arrays are different lengths

Answer (score 1):

A jQuery solution to fill the table body can be:

```js
var arrayOne = ['orange','blue','green','red','yellow','purple','gray','tan','pink','violet'];
var arrayTwo = ['1001','1003','3453','78934','2389','3','8934'];
var arrayThree = ['TV','phone','laptop'];
var arrayFour = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10'];
for (var i = 0; i <arrayOne.length; i++ ){
    var row = $('<tr/>').append($('<td/>', {text: arrayOne[i] || ''}))
            .append($('<td/>', {text: arrayTwo[i] || ''}))
            .append($('<td/>', {text: arrayThree[i] || ''}))
            .append($('<td/>', {text: arrayFour[i] || ''}));
    $('table tbody').append(row);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Column 1</th>
        <th>Column 2</th>
        <th>Column 3</th>
        <th>Column 4</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You have var row = $('<tr/>').append. So in my case do i need to find the modal table first. For example would it be $("#myModal").find(".table")$("<tr/>).append ?

Comment: @jumpman8947 Instead to use **$('table tbody').append(row);** you can write **$("#myModal").find(".table")**

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/phru3m7s/1/

```js
var arrayOne = ['orange','blue','green','red','yellow','purple','gray','tan','pink','violet'];
var arrayTwo = ['1001','1003','3453','78934','2389','3','8934'];
var arrayThree = ['TV','phone','laptop'];
var arrayFour = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10'];


for(var i=0; i< arrayOne.length; i++){
 var tableString = "<tr>";
   tableString += "<td>" + arrayOne[i] + "</td>";
    tableString += "<td>" + ((typeof arrayTwo[i] === 'undefined') ? '' : arrayTwo[i]) + "</td>";
    tableString += "<td>" + ((typeof arrayThree[i] === 'undefined') ? '' : arrayThree[i])  + "</td>";
    tableString += "<td>" + ((typeof arrayFour[i] === 'undefined') ? '' : arrayFour[i]) + "</td>";
  tableString += "<tr>";
  
  $('table tbody').append(tableString);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>Column 1</th>
          <th>Column 2</th>
          <th>Column 3</th>
          <th>Column 4</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arrayOne = ['orange','blue','green','red','yellow','purple','gray','tan','pink','violet'];
var arrayTwo = ['1001','1003','3453','78934','2389','3','8934'];
var arrayThree = ['TV','phone','laptop'];
var arrayFour = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10'];

//To test the longest array
var length_array = [];
length_array.push( arrayOne.length); 
length_array.push( arrayTwo.length); 
length_array.push( arrayThree.length); 
length_array.push( arrayFour.length); 

var maxLength = Math.max.apply( null, length_array );

for (var i = 0; i <maxLength; i++ ){
    var row = $('<tr/>').append($('<td/>', {text: arrayOne[i] || ''}))
            .append($('<td/>', {text: arrayTwo[i] || ''}))
            .append($('<td/>', {text: arrayThree[i] || ''}))
            .append($('<td/>', {text: arrayFour[i] || ''}));
    $('table tbody').append(row);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Column 1</th>
        <th>Column 2</th>
        <th>Column 3</th>
        <th>Column 4</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Approach to combine your individual arrays into one array and determine which is the longest  then loop over that to generate the rows

```js
var arrayOne = ['orange', 'blue', 'green', 'red', 'yellow', 'purple', 'gray', 'tan', 'pink', 'violet'],
  arrayTwo = ['1001', '1003', '3453', '78934', '2389', '3', '8934'],
  arrayThree = ['TV', 'phone', 'laptop'],
  arrayFour = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'];

var columns = [arrayOne, arrayTwo, arrayThree, arrayFour];
// start from longest column array
var rows = columns.reduce((a, c) => {
    return c.length > a.length ? c : a;
  }, [])
  // map the longest to create all the rows
  .map((_, rowIdx) => {
    // map the cells for each row
    var cells = columns.map(colArr => $('<td>',{text: colArr[rowIdx] || '' }));
    // return new row and cells
    return $('<tr>').append(cells);    
  });
 
// append all the rows     
$('#myModal tbody').append(rows);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myModal">
  <table>
     <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Column 1</th>
          <th>Column 2</th>
          <th>Column 3</th>
          <th>Column 4</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a modern and reasonably elegant way to do this using [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), as you can see in the example below:

```js
var arrayOne = ['orange', 'blue', 'green', 'red', 'yellow', 'purple', 'gray', 'tan', 'pink', 'violet'];
var arrayTwo = ['1001', '1003', '3453', '78934', '2389', '3', '8934'];
var arrayThree = ['TV', 'phone', 'laptop'];
var arrayFour = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'];
var sumArray = [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}];
var mergedArrays = [arrayOne, arrayTwo, arrayThree, arrayFour].reduce(function(sum, value, index) {
  for (var key in sum) {
    sum[key][index] = value[key];
  }
  return sum;
}, sumArray);

console.log(mergedArrays);

var htmlToRender = '<table class="table table-striped"><thead><tr><th>Column 1</th><th>Column 2</th><th>Column 3</th><th>Column 4</th></tr></thead><tbody>';

for (var key in mergedArrays) {
  htmlToRender += '<tr><td>' + mergedArrays[key][0] + '</td>';
  htmlToRender += '<td>' + mergedArrays[key][1] + '</td>';
  htmlToRender += '<td>' + mergedArrays[key][2] + '</td>';
  htmlToRender += '<td>' + mergedArrays[key][3] + '</td></tr>';
}

htmlToRender += '</tbody></table>';
$("#myModal").append(htmlToRender);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myModal">
</div>
```

#### Explanation

You essentially create an empty array of objects and then you accumulate the values of your existing arrays as objects with 4 values. After this is all done, you can iterate over the array of objects and write a new row in the table for each object in the array.

The code can be easily expanded and tweaked for more complex cases. Also, the length of the `sumArray` can be variable and tweaked based on your needs.

Also, as pointed out in this answer's comments, appending closing tags is a really bad practice, so the above code uses a better one, rendering the whole table instead of only its contents and the closing tags.

Comment: The concept of appending closing tags is all wrong. Not how the dom works

Comment: @charlietfl I totally agree with you, but the OP used this code, so I followed. I strongly disagree with using closing tags and, as a matter of fact, the optimal way in my opinion would be to render the whole table, as it makes little to no difference in the JS code and provides for a slightly easier manipulation and rendering. That's just me, though.

Comment: Doesn't matter that OP used it.... it does nothing and in fact can cause unexpected behavior. OP is misunderstanding how the dom works also

Comment: @charlietfl Agreed, it's a terrible idea. I actually updated my answer after researching it a little bit further. Thanks for pointing that out, appreciate it!